# change text with Id by selecting an image with Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, jquery-selectors

I have a query that makes changes on a list item's text while the mouse is over an image, I put an event target within the query  :

```
    $('img').on('mouseover', function(){
     // I would like an Id of a text instead of the 'li'
      $('li').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    });

    $('img').on('mouseout', function(){
      $('li').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    });
```

but I want that change it to be applied to only the item which have the same Id as the image :

```
s[i++] = '<li id=\"'+  vizList[j].name +'\">';
s[i++] =  '<a>'+ vizList[j].name + '</a>';
s[i++] =  '<img id=\"'+  vizList[j].name +'\" src="../renderer/bundles/' + vizList[j].icon + '" width="268" height="120" style="display:block"/>';
s[i++] = '</li>';
```

Comment: id's must be unique in an HTML document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the below code what you expect?

```
$('img').on('mouseover', function(event){
  $(event.target).closest('li').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
});

$('img').on('mouseout', function(event){
  $(event.target).closest('li').css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, ID is supposed to be unique, so either make them slightly different, or use classes.

Change your `$('li')` selector to `$(this).find('li')`. That should find the image within the hovered `li`

You can also use the `.hover` function to convert this into one call:

https://jsfiddle.net/juk41yLs/1/

```js
$('img').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).parent('li').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).parent('li').css('text-decoration', 'none');
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    Hover over this > 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to change the `li` contained `img` when mouse hovers over `img`. Then you should do it like this:

```
$('img').on('mouseover', function(event){

    $(this).parent().css('text-decoration', 'underline');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
   $('img').on('mouseover', function(event){
     // I would like an Id of a text instead of the 'li'
      var imgId = event.target.id;
      
      $('#' + imgId).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    });
```